# Bowl of the spherical cap and its diameter

Tags: geometry

Bowl has the shape of spherical cap. Its height is v=15 cm. If you want all the water in the bowl to leak out, you must to tilt the bowl at least 60°.

like this:

[image]

What is the inner diameter of the widest part of the bowl, calculated to the nearest mm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice picture, very helpful for the solution.  Actually, the picture *is* the solution, it is where the real mathematics is.  Once we *see* what's happening, the rest is essentially mechanical. We use the *tilted* version of the picture.

For $60^\circ$ to be the smallest angle at which all the water leaks out, the line at the bottom must be *tangent* to the sphere at the point of contact.  Let the point of contact, and tangency, be $T$.

Draw the vertical line at the point $T$ of tangency. This line goes through the centre $O$ of the sphere. Join $O$ to the bottom point $B$ of the bowl. Suppose that the line $OB$ meets the top surface of the water at $M$. Thus $M$ is the centre of the circle that used to be the top surface of the water.

Note that $\angle OTM$ is $30$ degrees.  If $R$ is the radius of the complete sphere of which the bowl is a part, then $OM=R-15$.

The ratio $\frac{R-15}{R}$ is the sine of the $30$ degree angle, so $\frac{R-15}{R}=\frac{1}{2}$, and therefore $R=30$.

We want the distance $MT$, which is the side of a right-angled triangle with hypotenuse $30$ and other side $15$ (because $30-15=15$). Thus, by the Pythagorean Theorem,  $MT= \sqrt{30^2-15^2}$. Double to get the diameter. Equivalently, we can use the fact that $\frac{MT}{R}$ is the cosine of the $30$ degree angle.

**Remark:** The angle $60$ is a "nice" angle. That made the calculation easier. However, if it had been the less nice angle of say $61^\circ$, the calculation would have the same structure. Then $\frac{R-15}{R}$ would be the sine of the $29$ degree angle. Solve for $R$, and use the Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: Thank you, that's right. :)